# Is it possible to throw Kirby back into the game?

Tags: kirbys-pinball-land

In Kirby's Pinball Land, if you fall down the hole at the bottom of the bottom board, you land on the plunger-type thing that you use to launch Kirby in the first place.

It tells you to push A, which theoretically would launch Kirby again, but it seems that no matter how hard I try to time it, he never gets back into the game.

Is it actually possible to shoot Kirby back onto the board and continue playing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to re-launch him into the play area, thus getting him a "second chance". I haven't played this game in about 12 years, but I believe the launch mechanic acts like a spring board - wait for a bit after he lands on the board, then hit A when the platform's descent slows down. Trying to re-launch him as soon as he hits the board won't work.

You can actually save Kirby through this method multiple times per lives, as long as you get the timing right. It becomes increasingly harder (per life) every time you successfully save yourself, because the platform actually decreases in size.

Below is a video of someone executing this correctly in their game: